# Trying to get detailed data dumps from new google nest e thermostat

Tags: smart-device, nest-device-access

I bought a nest thermostat as I thought it would be able to give me detailed data to showing the target temp and the actual as well as time etc. I needed this for various reasons.

However, it seems the official API "Works with Nest" was closed by Google. I've been able to get postman to ping the same location that the Google Nest Webapp hits and get back the data I need. I want to create a simple webapp to keep polling and save the data locally. However, I'm unable to find the OAuth Client Secret that the Nest Webapp uses to get the authorization code. I had to login via the webapp to get the code in one of the request and then test it out using postman.

- Is there any other API that will allow my to poll this data for my Nest easier?
- If there isn't another API, is there a way to get the Client ID and Client Secret form the Nest Webapp so I can drop that in mine to use? (I know its hacky, but am I think I'm out of options)

Comment: Seems like the Hombridge plugin for this still works here: https://github.com/chrisjshull/homebridge-nest. I haven't tried it, but the "Using Google Account" Section seems to have what I need. The full plugin might also do the control aspect if anyone is interested in that. Not sure why this took me so long to find. Will report back if I get it to work

Answer (score 0):

We don't provide support for using Google Nest internal APIs externally. Those are only for Nest App usage.

Comment: Good to know. In that case, could you answer the OP's first question by describing the supported way to programmatically obtain temperature from the Google Nest? For my own needs, I found the "Device Access" program which mentions temperature but I can't tell if that includes access to downloading past temperature data: https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/api/thermostat